# How to get audio samples from audio element in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, audio

i want to make an animation which will depend on the sound volume (e.g. it will be brighter when volume is more loud and darker when more quiet). I found an algorithm to get the volume of an part of audio, but I need audio samples to use this. So i have an `audio` element which looks like this:

```
<audio preload="auto" src="my/path.mp3"></audio>
```

I'm making it using `new Audio();` and i have it in variable `audio`. I have read an article: https://wiki.mozilla.org/Audio_Data_API and it told that I can use `MozAudioAvailable`, and it looks like that:

```
function loadedMetadata() {
        channels          = audio.mozChannels;
        rate              = audio.mozSampleRate;
        frameBufferLength = audio.mozFrameBufferLength;
         
        fft = new FFT(frameBufferLength / channels, rate);
}
function audioAvailable(event) {
        var fb = event.frameBuffer,
            signal = new Float32Array(fb.length / channels),
            magnitude;

        for (var i = 0, fbl = frameBufferLength / 2; i < fbl; i++ ) {
          signal[i] = (fb[2*i] + fb[2*i+1]) / 2;
        }
}
var audio = document.getElementById('audio-element');
audio.addEventListener('MozAudioAvailable', audioAvailable, false);
audio.addEventListener('loadedmetadata', loadedMetadata, false);
```

So in variable `signal` there are samples which I want to get, but it looks like `MozAudioAvailable` event doesn't exist in HTML and any docs which I read. So how to get audio samples from an Audio element? Or maybe now there's an alias of `MozAudioAvailable`?

Thank you.

Comment: You should look into the [Web Audio API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Audio_API), specifically the [`AnalyserNode`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/AnalyserNode) which can read frequency and waveform data while playing audio.

Comment: AnalyserNode is exactly what i needed, thank you!